# ArrayList null in jsp servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

My ArrayList is null, why?

**JSP**

```
    <jsp:include page="/ServletCargaEstacionamiento"></jsp:include>
    <% ArrayList<Estacionamiento> estacionamientos = (ArrayList <Estacionamiento >) request.getSession().getAttribute("est"); %>
```

**ServletCargaEstacionamiento.java**

```
    DAOEstacionamiento daoe = new DAOEstacionamiento();
    ArrayList<Estacionamiento> estacionamientos = daoe.select();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("est", estacionamientos);
```

**DAOEstacionamiento**

```
        while(rs.next()){
            estacionamientos.add(new Estacionamiento(rs.getInt("idEstacionamiento"), rs.getString("lugar")));}
```

Comment: Did you tried my answer bro?

Answer (score 0):

Call the Servlet by the URL which matches its `<url-pattern>` in `web.xml`, e.g. `http://example.com/contextname/ServletCargaEstacionamiento`.

You call the servlet which in turn forwards to the JSP to display the results. Create a Servlet which does something like following in `doGet()` method.

```
DAOEstacionamiento daoe = new DAOEstacionamiento();
ArrayList<Estacionamiento> estacionamientos = daoe.select();
request.getSession().setAttribute("est", estacionamientos);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/result.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and in `/WEB-INF/result.jsp`

```
<% ArrayList<Estacionamiento> estacionamientos = (ArrayList <Estacionamiento >) request.getSession().getAttribute("est"); %>
```